# How to play co-op split screen versus/horde on pc in Gears of War 4?

Tags: pc, gears-of-war-4

I'm trying to play the co-op versus or horde mode on split screen PC using two controllers but it is not giving me the option. I am able to activate the guest account on co-op campaign but versus, horde are giving me no options
[image: As you can see I got the option with player 2 guest login]
As you can see I got the option with player 2 guest login in co-op campaign

[image: The co-op versus with bots gives no such options]
The co-op versus with bots gives no such options

[image: The default screen gives no options for adding guest players]
The default screen gives no options for adding guest players

[image: The xbox mode in windows has no option to login the second controller]
The xbox mode in windows has no option to login the second controller

Really stuck here, would appreciate the setup help if at all or to know if it's no feasible